# c++ merge sort not working and crashing

Tags: c++, mergesort

I was trying to implement merge sort in c++ in the following way:

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::string;
using std::memcpy;

void mergeSort(int *array, int *temp, int leftStart, int rightEnd);
void mergeHalves(int *array, int *temp, int leftStart, int rightEnd);

void printArray(int* array, int size,string message){
    cout<<message<<endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        cout << *(array+i) << "\t";
    cout << endl;
}
int main(){
    const int size = 10;
    int myInts[size] = {9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0};
    int temp[size] = {0};
    printArray(myInts,size,"Input");
    mergeSort(myInts, temp, 0, size-1);
    printArray(myInts, size, "Output:");

    return 0;
}

void mergeSort(int *array, int *temp, int leftStart, int rightEnd){
    if (leftStart >= rightEnd)
        return;

    int middle = (leftStart + rightEnd) / 2;

    mergeSort(array, temp, leftStart, middle);
    mergeSort(array, temp, middle + 1, rightEnd);
    mergeHalves(array,temp,leftStart,rightEnd);
    return;
}

void mergeHalves(int *array, int *temp, int leftStart, int rightEnd){
    int leftEnd = (rightEnd + leftStart) / 2;
    int rightStart = leftEnd + 1;
    int size = rightEnd - leftStart + 1;

    int left = leftStart;
    int right = rightStart;
    int index = leftStart;

    while (left <= leftEnd && right <= rightEnd){
        if (*(array+left) <= *(array+right)){
            *(temp+index) = *(array+left);
            left++;
        }else{
            *(temp+index) = *(array+right);
            right++;
        }
        index++;
    }

    memcpy(temp + index, array + left, (leftEnd - left + 1) * sizeof(int));
    memcpy(temp + index, array + right, (rightEnd - right + 1) * sizeof(int));
    memcpy(array, temp, size * sizeof(int));
}
```

I have checked the code more and more times and I cannot manage to understand what I am missing.
The algorithm was not working properly with an initial value of

```
myInts[size] = {3, 6, 4, 2, 7, 8, 9, 1, 0, 5}
```

as it sorted only the first half of the array.
Then I tried to change the input with the one shown in the code, and I got the following output:

```
Input
9   8   7   6   5   4   3   2   1   0   
Output:
3   2   1   0   -161742639  6   5   4   7   8   
Abort trap: 6
```

After a while I recompiled and ran THE SAME CODE and got this output instead:

```
Input
9   8   7   6   5   4   3   2   1   0   
Output:
3   2   1   0   6   5   4   7   8   9
```

It seems to me that some assignment operation or copy operation went wrong and at random too, but everything seems right to me..
I've tried with step by step debugging and the flow of the program seems ok.

 I'm running on MacOS X Sierra 10.12.6, I'm compiling with g++. 

What am I missing? I'm getting crazy.. Thanks in advance!

 EDIT: I seem to have solved the `Abort Trap` problem, I edited the code passing `size-1` instead of `size` in the `main` function. Still ordering does not work though

Comment: Time to step through your code with a debugger. Looks like you're indexing outside an array.

Comment: How can an index go out of bounds randomly at runtime?

Comment: You pass `size` into the mergesort function as `rightEnd`. `rightEnd` is never changed and is eventually passed into `mergeHalves` as `rightEnd` (remember, it still has the value of `size`). You then loop `while(...right <= rightEnd)`, so at some point you'll end up dereferencing `(array+right)` when `right` is `size`, which is out of bounds. Note: this is just what I noticed from skimming through, there are probably other issues. I'd highly suggest a debugger (see [gdb](http://web.eecs.umich.edu/~sugih/pointers/summary.html)). Furthermore, you would've caught this if you were using vectors!

Comment: I wanted to go "the hard way" without using vectors! :P By the way I noticed that passing `size` and not `size-1` was wrong. Still ordering does not work. I'll look into what you've written right now

Comment: @magicleon your index does not go out of bounds randomly. What you see is the undefined behaviour. Whatever is in that index is returned. The value in there may or may not be what you expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a LOT of debugging for you, I've found your issue. You have named multiple variables the same thing through your different functions. Some of these variables mean exactly the same thing (`leftStart`, `rightEnd`), while others, like `size` mean two completely different things.

At the end of `mergHalves`, you do `memcpy(array, temp, size * sizeof(int));` probably because you were thinking `size` is the size of the whole array so you're copying everything back over. However, it's **not**.

That line should be `memcpy(array+leftStart, temp+leftStart, size * sizeof(int));` since in this function you've declared size to be `int size = rightEnd - leftStart + 1;`. This is a good example of why making your variable names a little longer and more descriptive can save you a few hours of debugging (and having to post on StackOverflow).

See the fix in action on [ideone](http://ideone.com/YNWhmE).

Lastly, as an aside, I understand that you want to try doing this "the hard way," without vectors, but please please please don't ever do something like `*(temp+index)`. The [subscript operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/th52k9c8.aspx) was made for that exact purpose and means the *exact same thing*, just a lot more readable. (ie, do `temp[index]` instead).

Comment: First of all, thank you for the debugging. Well I was not thinking that `size` was the whole array size but just `rightEnt  leftStart + 1`... I confused and did not realize what I was copying in the last `memcpy` of `mergeHalves`... I'm feeling very stupid right now lol. Thanks a lot, you're a life saver. Talking about the subscript operator, I did not notice that writing `*(temp+index)` was THAT awful, but after this "hell reading" well, I think that I've learned that too. Thanks again!